# Make 2 existing tags synonyms of a 3rd existing one

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

There are 3 tags: [xacml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml), [xacml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml2), and [xacml3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml3). There is no value in having [xacml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml2) and [xacml3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml3). The standard is similar enough that we can refer to [xacml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xacml) collectively.

How do I request that an admin take care of it?

I tried to do it myself but I got the following message:
[image: XACML Synonym]

PS: I had already asked the question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295917/how-can-i-convert-a-tag-to-being-a-synonym) but was redirected to SO Meta.

Comment: How ? You ask it in Meta and community will decide, then mods will apply it or not following the will of the community :)

Comment: Great, thanks for the​ info

Comment: Does this question count as asking? ;-)